# Running stanford moss because of institution proxy

Tags: perl, plagiarism-detection

I am running moss by Stanford.
I am using Perl script sent by Stanford at the time of registration.
but it is giving error as :

```
Checking files . . .
OK
Could not connect to server moss.stanford.edu: Connection refused
```

I tried adding institute proxy also in the code as follows :

```
$sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                  ProxyAddr   => '10.3.100.207',
                                   ProxyPort   => '8080',
                                  PeerAddr => $server,
                                  PeerPort => $port,
                                  Proto => 'tcp',
                                 );
```

But it is giving the same error as above. 
One possible solution is to set up a virtual environment and run the script. 
But what can be another solution ?

Comment: There are no Proxy\* parameters for IO::Socket::INET so your parameters simply get ignored. Also, there is no general concept for a TCP proxy but there are HTTP proxies and there are SOCKS4/SOCKS5 proxies. It is unknown what you have here and your script is unknown too so it is impossible to help you here with the current information.

Comment: How about trying to contact the author/distributor of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did and it worked.
I used Google colab for it.
I uploaded the files to be checked for plagiarism and the perl script to colab and then ran the perl script in the notebook

```
!perl moss.pl -l python -m 53 -c "Files" ./*.py
```